# Why didn't Sphinx upload a new video to evacuate the people from the airport?

Tags: zankyou-no-terror

I'm watching *Terror in Resonance*, the airport episode. Sphinx goes through a lot of trouble to find the hidden bomb - even risking their own identities. Their intention is to keep everyone away from harm.

Why don't they just upload a new video literally saying "*we're gonna blow up the airport*"?

At this point, Sphinx has gained so much media influence that it would instantly go viral (just like with their previous videos). The airport (and anyone else) would most certainly take such video seriously and evacuate.

This way, there would be no casualties, which is what they want. The bomb would still detonate and cause several structural damages, but that would not be anything new or surprising considering Sphinx literally blew up a skyscraper in the first episode anyway.

Comment: Announcing in a crowded space, "There is a bomb," is ***extraordinarily*** dangerous. Without a proper evacuation procedure, you'd risk more lives than you'd save. (*Disclaimer: I have not seen the episode, so this may not fit the circumstances.*)

Comment: @キルア that makes sense, yeah. Although it was planted by a sadistic antagonist who hid it in a plane, and then drove the plan against the airport. I feel like the risk of causing a ruckus would be worth it given the nature of the antagonist.

Comment: Think about it this way, if you were *Five,* how would you react to the video? *Nine* and *Twelve* knew that it wouldn't end in their favor.

Comment: @キルア I would write that as an answer, it certainly fits and makes sense

Answer (score 1):

If they did that, the real bomber (it's been too long, was it Five?) could easily detonate the bomb then and there to maximize casualties. Sphinx wanted to be discrete, since they didn't have control of the situation as they did with the skyscraper.